# Error in quarto - vecseq() when uploading .csv file

Tags: r, quarto

I keep on getting errors trying to upload .csv files onto quarto. It keeps on giving me this error:

The code I'm trying

````
```{r}
#| warning: false
#| echo: false
library(data.table)
library(flextable)
fread("mimic_admissions.csv") |> 
  flextable(cwidth = c(1, 1, 1, 4)) |> 
  fontsize(size = 8)
```
````

```
Quitting from lines 84-89 [unnamed-chunk-3] (test2.qmd)
Error in `vecseq()`:
! Join results in 836 rows; more than 285 = nrow(x)+nrow(i). Check for duplicate key values in i each of which join to the same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try by=.EACHI to run j for each group to avoid the large allocation. If you are sure you wish to proceed, rerun with allow.cartesian=TRUE. Otherwise, please search for this error message in the FAQ, Wiki, Stack Overflow and data.table issue tracker for advice.
Backtrace:
  1. global .main()
  2. execute(...)
  3. rmarkdown::render(...)
  4. knitr::knit(knit_input, knit_output, envir = envir, quiet = quiet)
  5. knitr:::process_file(text, output)
     ...
 27. flextable:::knit_to_latex(x, bookdown = is_bookdown, quarto = is_quarto)
 28. flextable:::gen_raw_latex(...)
 30. data.table::merge.data.table(...)
 32. data.table:::`[.data.table`(...)
 33. data.table:::vecseq(...)
```

The dataset I'm trying to upload is from MIMIC iii database, it might have some repeating values ie. "FEMALE / MALE" depending on subject-ids.

Anyone know what this error might mean?

I've tried to make a smaller dataset from the database as I thought it might be due to inner_join functions but no luck.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Given the data in `mimic_admissions.csv` (what is it?  We can't see it...),  what is your expected output?  Your code can be interpreted successfully, so it is syntactically correct.  The problem lies in how your code is responding to your data.  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a *minimal reproducible* example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: Please provide a link to the dataset you are trying to use!